# Resettable timer with System.Reactive

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I want to use `IObservable.Timeout()` to detect a data-source has gone "offline". This data source is a serial connection which is read inside a loop.

The read operation is intentionally blocking, and if I don't receive any data for a predefined period, I want to cancel the operation. Else, each time I receive data, I want the timed-out observable to generate an item, thus resetting the timeout.

My doubts are in the form of comments below:

```
void Run()
{
    IObservable<object> timeoutWatcher = CreateResettableTimer();

    timeoutWatcher.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(_cancellation.Cancel());

    while (!_cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {               
        var frameVals = FTDIHelper.ReadAvailableBytes(_handle, 8); // blocking;

        DoSomethingWith(frameVals);

        // ??? How do I "add" an item to timeoutWatcher ???
    }
}

IObservable<object> CreateResettableTimer()
{
    // ??? What should I return, and how to create it ??? 
    // Use a Subject? If not, what else then?
    // Should it be returning IObservable<object> or other type?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Timeout` operator to specify a timeout (this makes semantic sense) for an observable which does not produce a value within the specified time. The timeout propagates an `OnError` which you can subscribe to - this does cause the timeout pipeline to be torn down but you can use `Retry` to apply resubscription logic.  Use `OnError` to apply your cancellation logic. You can also handle non-timeout errors through the same pipeline.

Here's an example with a simulated 'task' that takes a random amount of time to complete, and a timeout being detected if it's any longer than two seconds.

```
var randomSource =
    Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().NextDouble() * 5))).Repeat().Publish(); 

randomSource
    .Do(v => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now))
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) 
    .Do(_ => { }, err => Console.Write("\t\t\tTimed out\r")) //on error callback
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(); //set up the pipeline

randomSource.Connect();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
6/26/2017 7:15:42 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:15:43 PM
6/26/2017 7:15:46 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:15:47 PM
6/26/2017 7:15:51 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:15:56 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:16:00 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:16:02 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:02 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:05 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:16:06 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:08 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:08 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:10 PM
6/26/2017 7:16:13 PM    Timed out
6/26/2017 7:16:18 PM    Timed out
```

As you can see, anything above two seconds times out.

Comment: Nice! The `OnError` method is what I was missing, I was subscribing to `OnNext` instead and so was "getting the timeout" right from the start... Also, the `Do` method is interesting, I didn't know it, and I'll study that. Thanks!

Comment: @heltonbiker `Do` allows you to express side effects in the pipeline. It's not very functional to do stuff in `Subscribe` (it doesn't compose). I sorta hoped this example would demo a bunch of different features together.

Comment: Exactely. I also thought about `Do` as a "composable subscribe" of sorts. Quite useful when needed.